# Adding points of an elliptic curve over a finite field

Tags: finite-fields, elliptic-curves, cryptography

I'm a bit confused with how fractions are handled with adding points of elliptic curves over finite fields. Below is an example from the text which I am trying to understand:

[image]

The part that particularly confuses me is

[image]

If I think about this the same way that $1/5$ was handled, we have that $246/1 = 246\cdot1^{-1}=246\cdot1=246$, but $246\equiv12 \mod 13$ so shouldn't $246/1 = 12$? I don't understand how the calculation is being done. Could someone explain?

Comment: Hmm, the text seems to be in error.

Comment: @anon http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/430836/doubling-a-point-on-an-elliptic-curve?rq=1 referring to this post my calculation seems to make sense, so you are probably right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right. The text is just missing a minus sign. The answer is
$$\lambda \equiv 12 \equiv -1 \mod 13.$$