# Scalar Point Multiplication for Elliptic Curve Diffie-Hellman Key Exchange

Tags: elliptic-curves, cryptography, computational-mathematics

I am trying to understand  elliptic curve  Diffie-Hellman key exchange and here is a book example which I don't understand. Given values of $G=(2,2)$ and I should calculate $203(2,2)$, which actually is $(130,203$). I can do the arithmetic for small numbers but in this case I am very confuses

Comment: You should give more information about your elliptic curve. You need point doubling.

Comment: Thank you. The curve  is of order (0,4) which is the same as y^2=×^3-4

Comment: You can edit your question with this information, see at Wikipedia  [Elliptic_curve_point_multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve_point_multiplication) and[Doubling a point on an elliptic curve](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/430836/doubling-a-point-on-an-elliptic-curve)

Comment: @Moo the book is William Stallings-  Cryptography and network security, 4th edition, example  is on the top of the page 312

Comment: @Moo thank you very much. Actually i have never heard about horners rule but i googled it and probably now i can use it. Thank you a lot.

Comment: @Moo if it is possible, i will be very glad as i need the inf for my final exam. Besides, the first method seems very time consuming

Comment: @Moo thank you very much. You completely explained the problem. Thank you as well for the corrections.

Answer (score 2):

From the book "Cryptography and Network Security: Principles and Practice" by W. Stallings, we have the following example.

$$y^2 = x^3 - 4 \pmod{211}$$

- **I took the liberty to correct the errors and typos in this example!**
- A generator point is $G = (2,2)$.
- For $G = (2,2)$, one can calculate the point of infinity for this generator as $241G = O$.
- A’s private key is $n_A = 121$, so A’s public key is $P_A = 121(2,2) = (115,48)$.
- B’s private key is $n_B = 203(2,2)$, so B’s public key is $P_B = 203(2,2) = (130,203)$.
- The shared secret key is $121(130,203) = 203(115,48) = (161,69)$.

Your question is how do they calculate the point multiplication $203(2,2) = (130,203)$?

Other than addition, with $n$ being a natural number, we can define another operation:  scalar multiplication as $$nP = \underbrace{P + P + \cdots + P}_{n\ \text{times}}.$$

Written in that form, it may seem that computing $nP$ requires $n$ additions. If $n$ has $k$ binary digits, then our algorithm would be $O(2^k)$, which is not really good. But there are many faster algorithms. One of them is the double and add algorithm.

We have $n = 203$. Its binary representation is $11001011_2$. This binary representation can be turned into a sum of powers of two: $$\begin{array}{rcl} 203 & = & 1 \cdot 2^7 + 1 \cdot 2^6 + 0 \cdot 2^5 + 0 \cdot 2^4 + 1 \cdot 2^3 + 0 \cdot 2^2 + 1 \cdot 2^1 + 1 \cdot 2^0 \\ & = & 2^7+2^6+2^3+2^1+2^0\end{array}$$

(We have taken each binary digit of $n$ and multiplied it by a power of two.)

In view of this, we can write: $$203 \cdot P = 2^7 P + 2^6 P + 2^3 P + 2^1 P + 2^0 P$$

In words, the [*Double and Add*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve_point_multiplication#Double-and-add) algorithm works as follows:

- Take $P$.
- Double it, so that we get $2P$.
- Add $2P$ to $P$ so the we get the result of $2^1P + 2^0P$.
- Double $2P$, so that we get $2^2P$, but don't perform any addition with it.
- Double $2^2P$ to get $2^3P$.
- Add it to our result so that we get $2^3P + 2^1P + 2^0P$.
- Double $2^3P$ to get $2^4P$, but don't perform any addition with it.
- Double $2^4P$ to get $2^5P$, but don't perform any addition with it.
- Double $2^5P$ to get $2^6P$.
- Add it to our result so that we get $2^6P + 2^3P + 2^1P + 2^0P$.
- Double $2^6P$ to get $2^7P$.
- Add it to our result so that we get $2^7+ 2^6P + 2^3P + 2^1P + 2^0P$.
- In the end, we can compute $203 \cdot P$ performing just seven doublings and four additions!

To carry out these calculations, we use the [*Point Addition*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve_point_multiplication#Point_addition) and [*Point Doubling*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve_point_multiplication#Point_doubling) formulas while taking care regarding the point at infinity. The intermediate calculations are

- $P = (2,2)$
- $2P = (5,200)$
- $2P + P = (129,56)$
- $2^2 P = (159, 144)$
- $2^3 P = (174, 163)$
- $2^3 P + 2 P + P = (168, 6)$
- $2^4 P = (181, 209)$
- $2^5 P = (136, 11)$
- $2^6 P = (147, 97)$
- $2^6P + 2^3 P + 2 P + P = (32, 108)$
- $2^7 P = (133,48)$
- $2^7P + 2^6P + 2^3 P + 2 P + P = (130, 203)$

This verifies that $203 (2, 2) = (130, 203)$.

There are tools like [*SAGE*](http://www.sagemath.org/), [*Magma*](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/calc/), [*GAP*](https://www.gap-system.org/), [*Pari/GP*](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), [*Mathematica*](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/) or others that you can use to do these calculations.